# asp.net mvc - how to override default input value when value must be a number

Tags: asp.net-mvc, input, html-helper

Ive got an `Html.TextBoxFor` that is used to represent a `Double`.  When I generate "Create" View

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.Longitude)
```

The `<input>` has a default value of "0"

I have tried modifying it in two ways

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(Function(model) model.Longitude, New With {.value = ""})
```

and in the controller

```
Dim model As Domain.Event = New Domain.Event
With model
    .Longitude = String.Empty
End With

Return View(model)
```

But neither of these work.

How can I have the input "Blank" for a numeric input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [`Nullable(Of Double)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) type or `double?` in C#.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring, thanks for the info. Didn't know this. It's good to hear that VB.NET has also syntactic sugar support for nullable types. I will have to refresh my old VB.NET skills :-)

Comment: You can also use **Automatic Properties** in VB. `Public Something As String`

Answer (score 0):

Look at answer of  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/559846/asp-net-mvc-updatemodel-empty-property)

They overwrite default values in model binding.

You can derive your custom model binder from *DefaultModelBinder*.
You can add as many other Binders as you need.

Example:
Register your Binder in global.asax
in such way

`protected void Application_Start()    {
... your code ...
 ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new YourModelBinder();
.... your code...
}`